# How to send 404 for routes not defined in predicates path of spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway application with following yml config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: My gateway service
          uri: ${DEMO_URI}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/demo/**
```

Now I have also defined security config:-

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    log.debug("Configuring tenant web security");

    return http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(appProps.getAuthWhitelist().toArray(String[]::new)).permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .addFilterAt(authorizationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
        .build();
  }
```

Now for the requests for urls that is not defined in the yml is still going through the authentication filter. How can I skip that and send 404 for urls not defined in yml?

One idea I thought of is adding a custom web filter with highest precedence and add it to my security config and that filter will intercept the request and check for the path and return 404 but the problem with this one is how do I get the paths that is defined in yml configs in filter code?

Comment: Why do you even have custom filters. As soon as you add a custom filter you are basically ”opting out” of what spring security provides you. So configurations will not be valid and you have to handle all this stuff by yourself. My suggestion to you is too look into what spring security already has configurable and then ise the built in filters and configure them to your specific needs instead.

Comment: I need to handle custom logic for authentication and authorization. That is why I have added these filters.

Comment: And as i wrote before, adding custom filters opts out, you should instead customize included filters to your need instead.

Comment: Actually filters I have used are existing ones only but I have configured the respective authentication manager and authorization manager for them.

Comment: Well you have posted way to little code for me to take your word for it, you are adding filters manually, that is custom security. And thats how spring security works. I cant change it.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter should be called only if URI matches `/api/demo/**` path based on your given code.

Also if your filter is route specific then you can add that filter in routes definition directly like this.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: My gateway service
          uri: ${DEMO_URI}
          filters:
            - AuthenticationWebFilter
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/demo/**
```

and remove filter call from `SecurityWebFilterChain`.

Comment: `AuthenticationWebFilter` here is a spring security filter but not a gateway filter factory.

Comment: Can you post your yaml config for URL that you mentioned in post

Comment: I have already posted that I guess

Comment: In that case behavior is correct. Your gateway service routes request as per path. It does not know path is 404 since it is coming from downstream service, all it can do is check for auth. Hence auth gets called every time for every /api/demo/**. If you know upfront certain URL will yield 404 then you can add that rule like I mentioned in post.